# Renderizar imagen desde una API en Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, api, img, vue3

estoy haciendo una app en Vue 3 para aprender y todo me va bien excepto en una parte.

Tengo una ref en donde estoy recibiendo la respuesta de una llamada de una API. En el template uso el vfor para renderizar dinámicamente los datos, sin embargo, al momento de querer usar el campo src de la etiqueta  me toma la variable como un string y no me renderiza nada.

```
<template>
  <div v-if="result">
    <div v-for="r in result" :key="r.id">
      <div class="anime-container">
        <h1>{{ r.attributes.canonicalTitle }}</h1>
        <img src={{ r.image}} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else class="spinner">Cargando...</div>
</template>
```

El problema no es de la api ni de la variable pues efectivamente en r.image tengo una url que es la siguiente https://media.kitsu.io/anime/poster_images/42765/original.jpg?1619890522

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que usted mismo se esta dando la solución. Use:                 
 ``<img :src="r.image" />`` ya que requiere la url y no interpolaciones de texto.

Comment: @mafu haciéndolo así <img :src="r.image" /> no me sale ningún error pero al final la imagen no se renderiza... eso mismo me sucedió con unas imágenes en estático que tengo en el proyecto y tuve que hacer un require(url) el problema es que al hacer esto tampoco funciona <img :src="require(r.attributes.posterImage.Original)" />

Comment: Entonces, quizás  tiene que verificar la propiedad ``r.image`` porque al parecer no tiene la url

Answer (score 0):

En tu código, puedes arreglar el problema modificando la línea de la imagen de esta manera:

```
<img :src="`${r.image}`" />
```

Answer (score -1):

dentro de tu `v-for` puedes poner

```
 <img :src="`${r.image}`" />
```

y te cargara la imagen correctamente, a mi me funciono

Comment: Hola Oscar, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración. Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!